# return() versus pthread_exit() in pthread start functions

Tags: c++, linux, unix, pthreads

The following program shows that we can use `return` or `pthread_exit` to return a `void*` variable that is available to `pthread_join`'s status variable.

1. Should there be a preference for using one over the other?
2. Why does using return work? Normally we think of return putting a value on the stack but since the thread is completed the stack should vanish.  Or does the stack not get destroyed until after `pthread_join`?
3. In your work, do you see much use of the status variable?  It seems 90% of the code I see just NULLs out the status parameter. Since anything changed via the `void*` ptr is already reflected in the calling thread there doesn't seem much point to returning it.  Any new `void*` ptr returned would have to point to something `malloc`ed by the start thread, which leaves the receiving thread with the responsibility to dispose of it.  Am I wrong in thinking the status variable is semi-pointless?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

struct taskdata
{
       int  x;
     float  y;
    string  z;
};


void* task1(void *data)
{
    taskdata *t = (taskdata *) data;

    t->x += 25;
    t->y -= 4.5;
    t->z = "Goodbye";

    return(data);
}

void* task2(void *data)
{
    taskdata *t = (taskdata *) data;

    t->x -= 25;
    t->y += 4.5;
    t->z = "World";

    pthread_exit(data);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threadID;

    taskdata t = {10, 10.0, "Hello"};

    void *status;

    cout << "before " << t.x << " " << t.y << " " << t.z << endl;

    //by return()

    pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, task1, (void *) &t);

    pthread_join(threadID, &status);

    taskdata *ts = (taskdata *) status;

    cout << "after task1 " << ts->x << " " << ts->y << " " << ts->z << endl;

    //by pthread_exit()

    pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, task2, (void *) &t);

    pthread_join(threadID, &status);

    ts = (taskdata *) status;

    cout << "after task2 " << ts->x << " " << ts->y << " " << ts->z << endl;

}
```

With output of:

```
before 10 10 Hello
after task1 35 5.5 Goodbye
after task2 10 10 World
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

(1) In C++ code, using `return` causes the stack to be unwound and local variables destroyed, whereas `pthread_exit` is only guaranteed to invoke cancellation handlers registered with `pthread_cancel_push()`. On some systems this mechanism will also cause the destructors for C++ local variables to be called, but this is not guaranteed for portable code --- check your platform documentation.

Also, in `main()`, `return` will implicitly call `exit()`, and thus terminate the program, whereas `pthread_exit()` will merely terminate the thread, and the program will remain running until all threads have terminated or some thread calls `exit()`, `abort()` or another function that terminates the program.

(2) The use of `return` works because the POSIX specification says so. The returned value is stored in a place where `pthread_join()` can retrieve it. The resources used by the thread are not reclaimed until `pthread_join()` is called.

(3) I never use the return value of a thread in raw POSIX threads. However, I tend to use higher level facilities such as the Boost thread library, and more recently the C++0x thread library, which provide alternative means for transferring values between threads such as futures, which avoid the problems associated with memory management that you allude to.

Comment: With regards to (1), pthread_exit does not terminate the thread immediately, it runs cancellation handlers first. At least NPTL/g++ use the same mechanism for cancellation handlers and C++ dtors so pthread_exit does indeed unwind the stack in that case. Likewise, OpenVMS pthread_exit/thread cancellation unwinds the stack and runs C++ dtors. You should probably check the manual for your specific pthread implementation with regards to the behavior of pthread_exit and stack unwinding.

Comment: I've clarified (1) to take your comment into account.

Comment: I'm definitely buying your book :) (hope it comes out soon).

Answer (score 7):

I think that `return` from the `start_routine` is preferable, because it ensures that the call stack is properly unwound.

This is even more important for C than C++ since it doesn't have the destructor magic that cleans up the mess after preliminary exits. So your code should go through all final parts of routines on the call stack to do `free`s and alike.

For why this works, this is simple

> If the start_routine returns, the effect shall be as if there was an
>   implicit call to pthread_exit() using the return value of
>   start_routine as the exit status

For my personal experience I tend to not use the status of terminated threads much. This is why I often have the threads started `detached`. But this should depend much on the application and is certainly not generalizable.