# What does exactly the "status" in pthread_join represent and how to query it

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I'm wondering what exactly the "status" parameter in the pthread_join is for

```
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **status);
```

I'm trying to make use of it but I cannot understand what exactly does it represent.
According to the documentation

> status
>
> ```
> Is the location where the exit status of the joined thread is stored.
> ```
>
> This can be set to NULL if the exit
>   status is not required.

OK. That sounds nice. How do I use it? I've looked at some examples but I cannot 
get the hang of it(and some examples are plain wrong in using it). So I did go to 
the source. In the glibc implementation I found the following test for pthread_join:

```
...
pthread_t mh = (pthread_t) arg;
void *result;
...
if (pthread_join (mh, &result) != 0)
{
  puts ("join failed");
  exit (1);
}

here follows the WTF moment ...

if (result != (void *) 42l)
{
  printf ("result wrong: expected %p, got %p\n", (void *) 42, result);
  exit (1);
}
```

So the value of the result(which is an address) should be 42?? Is this something global 
at the library level, because I could not find anything specific in the [test](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/tst-join1.c;h=95a78ba0b546303801591021923a7f77656a2909;hb=master)?

EDIT: it seems [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692591/return-versus-pthread-exit-in-pthread-start-functions) provides info related to what I asked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The status is set to the value returned by the function that the thread starts executing (or from the value passed to pthread_exit() if the thread exits early).

Example:

```
 void* thread_func(void* data)
 {
     if (fail())
     {
         pthread_exit((void*)new int(2)); // pointer to int(2) returned to status
     }
     return (void*)new int(1); // pointer to int(1) returned to status;

     // Note: I am not advocating this is a good idea.
     //       Just trying to explain what happens.
 }

 pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_func, NULL);

 void*  status;
 pthread_join(thread, &status);
 int*   st = (int*)status;

 // Here status is a pointer to memory returned from thread_func()
 if ((*st) == 1)
 {
      // It worked.
 }
 if ((*st) == 2)
 {
      // It Failed.
 }
```

Comment: It seems pretty obvious now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Read the doc for `pthread_create`. The function that runs a thread is defined to return a `void*`. Whatever it returns, `pthread_join` delivers to you via the `void**`'. If the function chooses to return `(void *)42`, then '42' is what you will get.

Comment: I don't see any pthread_start in my doc. Only pthread_create and it does not have a clear link to the fact that status in pthread_join is the void* returned by my running function.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a bad doc. Next time read the specification: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html

Comment: Indeed a bad doc ... Thanks for the link!