# pthread_join causing seg fault

Tags: join, pthreads

As part of a pthreads tutorial exercise I wrote a program to create 10 threads than to join the 10 threads.  The program runs and prints the output however it seems that on the first call to pthread_join it causes a segmentation fault.  I am not sure why this is occurring.  I tried searching on web, however most issues where concerning invalid pointers passed to the function.  I am not sure if this is the same issue with my code, as I am not seeing it easily.

if anyone can help me, I certainly would appreciate it :)

code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NTHREADS    10

void *thread_function(void *arg)
{
    int i;
    int *coming = (int*) arg;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        printf("Hello, World (thread %d)\n", *coming);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    void *exit_status;
    int retVal;
    pthread_t pthread_array[NTHREADS];
    int randVals[10] = {23,5,17,55,9,47,69,12,71,37};

    printf("threads are created\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        retVal=pthread_create(&pthread_array[i], NULL, thread_function, &randVals[i]);
        printf("pthread_create %d retVal=%d\n", i, retVal);
    }

    printf("threads are joined\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        retVal= pthread_join(pthread_array[i], &exit_status);
        printf("pthread_join %d retVal=%d and exit_status=%d\n", i, retVal,
        *((int *)exit_status));
    }

    printf("all threads have ended\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem

```
printf("pthread_join %d retVal=%d and exit_status=%d\n", i, retVal,
    *((int *)exit_status));
```

your thread function returns NULL, and so this is the value stored in `exit_status`. So now in your `printf` you do this

```
*((int *)exit_status
```

you are casting this NULL pointer to a int* and then dereferencing it. Dereferencing NULL pointers is not a good idea. See this question for a fuller example of how to use `exit_status` [What does exactly the "status" in pthread_join represent and how to query it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385364/what-does-exactly-the-status-in-pthread-join-represent-and-how-to-query-it)

Answer (score 0):

```
    *((int *)exit_status));
```

If the thread function returns NULL (which it does), this will try to dereference it. Before doing so, you should test `exit_status`:

```
pthread_join(...);
if (exit_status != NULL)
    /* Safe to use. */
```

Comment: ugh... I should have tested for that thank you for the heads up!