# Accessing the return value using pthread_exit()

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, segmentation-fault, double-pointer

I have done the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct foo
{
   int a;
   int b;
};

void* thread_func1(void *arg)
{
   struct foo *temp = (struct foo*)malloc(sizeof(struct foo));

   temp->a = 10;
   temp->b = 20;

   pthread_exit(temp);
}

void* thread_func2(void *arg)
{
   pthread_exit((void*)100);
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t tid1, tid2;
   int err;
   struct foo *f;
   void *ret;

   err = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thread_func1, NULL);
   err = err | pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, thread_func2, NULL);

   if(err != 0)
   {
      perror("pthread_create()");
      exit(-1);
   }

   err = pthread_join(tid1, (void**)&f);
   if(err != 0 )
   {
      perror("pthread_join1");
      exit(-1);
   }

   printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", f->a, f->b); //Line1

   err = pthread_join(tid2, &ret);
   if(err != 0 )
   {
      perror("pthread_join2");
      exit(-1);
   }

   printf("ret = %d\n", *(int*)ret); //Line2

   return 0;

}
```

I get segmentation fault on Line2. What is wrong with Line2

If i modify Line2 to

> printf("ret = %d\n", (int)ret);

there is no segmentation fault and it prints the correct value(ie, 100). I do not understand why the modification works. I believe i have the wrong concept regarding the usage of double pointers. I would like to get it corrected.

What is the reason for the Segmentation fault and why the modification works?

Comment: Sidenote: Use `malloc` like this: `struct foo *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));` You will appreciate it when you understand the benefits.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you do not free the values returned by the first thread function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Point noted!. `free` has to be done after accessing the values using f->a and f->b right?

Comment: @LinuxPenseur, of course. `free` is done when you don't need the data anymore.

Comment: Thanks @all who have provided the answers, comments to make my code smarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return one number from the thread. In the first thread, that number is a `struct foo *`. Therefore, if you say

```
pthread_join(tid1, &ret);
```

then `ret` will contain that pointer (which is **not** a double pointer).

Similarly in the second case, you are returning `100` even though you are looking at it as if it's a `void *`. Nevertheless, the value is still `100`!

Therefore when you write

```
pthread_join(tid2, &ret);
```

`ret` will contain `100`, which is not a pointer, but a mere integer. That is why you should also cast it to `int`.

The reason you got a segmentation fault is that you look at `100` as an `int *` and then try to dereference it.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are returning the actual integer, not a pointer, but you access it as a pointer.

Comment: @Brady Yeah maybe... :) But your answer contains an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you're trying to dereferencce a pointer whose address is 100.

Instead of looking at the return value, why dont you pass in a pointer to what you want to assign in the thread_funcs? That is, use the "void *arg" arguments of thread_func1() and thread_func2()

Like this:

```
void* thread_func1(void *arg)
{
   struct foo **fooPtrPtr = (struct foo**) arg;
   *fooPtrPtr = (struct foo*)malloc(sizeof(struct foo));

   ...
}

void* thread_func2(void *arg)
{
   int *intPtr = arg;
   *intPtr = 100;
   ...
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t tid1, tid2;
   int err;
   struct foo *f;
   int ret;

   err = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thread_func1, &f);
   err = err | pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, thread_func2, &ret);
   ...
   printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", f->a, f->b); //Line1
   ...
   printf("ret = %d\n", ret); //Line2
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_exit((void*)100);` causes integer `100` to become exit status of your thread. It just abuses type cast so that `void*` is its type.
If you want to retrieve this value, you will have to use same type cast abuse in main thread as well:

```
int ret;
err = pthread_join(tid2, (void**) &ret);
// here you can work with ret as with any other integer
```

I also suggest you to use `return` instead of `pthread_exit`. Also note that memory dynamically allocated by using `malloc` should be freed by calling `free`. And type cast of return value of `malloc` is redundant here, it can be omitted.

This question could also help you: [Close a thread when done with it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10821618/1168156)