# "Un-casting" from (void *) and de-referencing to char array

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, pthreads, void-pointers

I have almost completed an homework assignment where I am required to use pthreads. I have figured out the pthreads. The only problem I have left is figuring out how to pass multiple arguments to threads through  pthread_create().

I need to pass two chars to the thread. I have to cast them to (*void) to use with pthread_create(). I can pass them, but I can't figure out how to get the values from *parameter in the function.

```
void *my_function(void *parameter) {

    /* ATTEMPT 1 - DOESN'T WORK */
    //char* arguments[2];
    //arguments = (char * [2]) parameter;
    /*Error message: 
    error: ISO C++ forbids casting to an array type char* [2] [-fpermissive]
    error: incompatible types in assignment of char** to char*[2]
    */

    /* ATTEMPT 2 - DOESN'T WORK */
    //char *my_data = (char *)parameter;
    //my_data is blank when I try to use cout to check it's values

    /* What I need to do is get those two chars from the array and print them out as part of this thread function */

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char duration = '5'; //in reality, this value is taken from argv but I am leaving that out for brevity

    pthread_t threads[3];

    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){

         char thread_args[2] = {i, duration};

         //create thread with arguments passed in
         int results = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, my_function, (void *) &thread_args);

         //testing for pthread error
         if (results){
             printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", results);
             exit(-1);
         }

     }

    /* Wait for all threads to complete */
    for (int j=0; j < num_threads; j++) { // https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/
        pthread_join(threads[j], NULL);
    }


    /* some information prints here that is unrelated to my problem (the date, time, etc) */

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I was able to pass one value through with no problem. Any suggestions?

The closest existing question I could find was this but I still am having no luck: [Converting from void* to char ** in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053716/converting-from-void-to-char-in-c)

Thank you!

Comment: Create an array or struct with the two chars and pass a pointer to either one.

Comment: @Code-Guru: `thread_args` appears to already be an array with the two chars.

Comment: @kelseyelayne: Do you know about the difference between `'\1'` and `'1'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that within this loop:

```
for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
    char thread_args[2] = {i, duration};
    int results = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, my_function, (void *) 
    ...
}
```

`thread_args` is a local array with automatic storage duration, lifetime of which is tied to each iteration so there is a chance that the memory where you store these arguments might be freed before the thread will access it, which would lead to **undefined behavior** in that case.

Much better approach would be to create a structure, that you would use to pass the data to this thread:

```
typedef struct {
    char duration;
    int num;
} ThreadData;
```

Then your code could look like this:

```
void *my_function(void *parameter) {
    // retrieve and print the thread data:
    ThreadData* td = (ThreadData*) parameter;
    printf("num = %d, duration = %c\n", td->num, td->duration);
    delete td;
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char duration = '5';
    pthread_t threads[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // create structure that will be passed to thread:
        ThreadData* td = new ThreadData;
        td->duration = duration;
        td->num = i;

        //create thread with arguments passed in:
        int ret = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, my_function, (void *) td);

        //testing for pthread error:
        if (ret) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", ret);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    // wait for all threads to complete:
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Also note that to end thread's execution it is better to use `return` than `pthread_exit` since with `return` it is guaranteed that variables within thread's routine will be destroyed and stack will be unwound. For more information see [return() versus pthread_exit() in pthread start functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3692591/1168156)

Comment: Although `td = static_cast<ThreadData*>(parameter)` might be more reasonable option than that C-style cast (`td = (ThreadData*) parameter;`).