# ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers

```
struct limit{
  int up;
  int down;
};

void *x;

struct limit *l;
l->up=1;
l->down=20;

x=l;

cout<<x->up;
```

This is part of my code I am getting error in last line **‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type**. I know last line in my code is wrong. I just want to know how to print up and down values using `x` variable.

Comment: You can't access any members through a `void` pointer. Why do you want to do this? Can you provide some context?

Comment: You have to _cast_ `x`. If you don't know what type-casting is, you should get some learning resources.

Comment: Note, you are using `l` uninitialized in the code above.

Comment: The compiler message actually says it all. Since `void*` isn't a pointer-to-object-type (as little as e.g. `int` or `bool` would be) you can't access any of its formally non-existing members. It really doesn't matter whether -- by accident -- the `void` pointer points at some structure that has those members.

Comment: Yep, explain why using `void *`?

Comment: i using pthreads. in that i should pass a arg of type void * we should pass only one arg so i want to pass struct so that i can get multiple values at a time @zoska

Comment: show us exact example of using pthreads in which you want to use void *, so we can exactly direct you in the right way.

Answer (score 5):

In this part:

```
struct limit *l;
l->up=1;
l->down=20;
```

you are dereferencing uninitialized pointer `l`, which results in ***undefined behavior***. However, even if you initialized it properly, after you assign it to `void*`, you can not dereference `void` pointer:

```
void* x = l;
cout<< x->up;
```

you need to explicitly cast it back to `struct limit*`:

```
void* x = l;
struct limit * y = static_cast<struct limit*>(x);
cout << y->up;
```

or yet even better: avoid using `void*` at first place.

---

Since you mentioned that you're doing this because of  [pthreads](/questions/tagged/pthreads), then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351207/1168156) will help you :)

Comment: Instead of **static_cast<struct limit*>** we can use **(limit *)**. It works

Comment: @rock: In this case (+ assuming this is C++), `static_cast` is more reasonable than C-style cast :)

Comment: we can used mixed c and c++ :)

Comment: After reading OP comment about using pthreads, I think he is having problems with retrieving void* data through thread function. If you could make some additional changes, then this answer should cover his problem :).

Comment: @zoska: I've added a link to related question instead :)

Comment: @rock: Have a look at the link I've added to my answer :)

Comment: @LihO thank you that what i needed i.e to pass multiple arguments through pthead_create
can you give link about pthreads and exercises for practice